# Como realizar transferencia de llamadas

Tags: android

Tengo una app que transfiere llamadas pero a partir de la version 6+ no funciona he probado con esto:

```
btn_transfer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                Uri uri2 = Uri.parse("tel:4");
                intent.setData(uri2);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ServicioCallerOverride.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
```

El resultado es: NO se ha podido realizar la transferencia. No da error en la aplicacion.

Answer (score 2):

Al dar clic al botón estas detectando si existe el permiso, si es así realizas el Intent, por lo tanto no se va a realizar el Intent ya que primeramente debes requerir permisos.

Agrega la petición del permiso:

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                    122);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este sería el código:

```
btn_transfer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                Uri uri2 = Uri.parse("tel:4");
                intent.setData(uri2);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ServicioCallerOverride.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{ //si no existe permiso, los requiere.
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                    122);
               }



            }
        });
```

**Importante: el usuario tiene que aceptar el permiso forzosamente, si no lo acepta no habrá forma de realizar la llamada, esto para dispositivos con android 6.0 o posterior**

Comment: Gracias por contestar, pero despues de buscar. Resulta que para la transferencia de llamadas tiene que activarlo el operador.

Comment: @JoseMa el usuario tiene que aceptar el permiso forzosamente, si no lo acepta no hay forma de realizar la llamada, esto para dispositivos con android 6.0 o posterior